# How do I run code without the PyCharm IDE

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Now that I am done with my project that was developed using PyCharm in a virtual environment, I need to distribute the code to my work machine; however, I am not certain on how to do this.  Do I need to create a build of sorts so the code an run independently of the PyCharm IDE?  Can someone please point me to the correct documentation on this crucial next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on what and how you're using the code for. If you just want to run it on your computer and it's a single file, you can open the command line/terminal and type `python3 your_file_name` and it will run the file (where your_file_name is the path to your .py file from whatever directory you're in). I assume you have python installed on your work machine, but if not, go here:

https://www.python.org/downloads/

If you have a more complex project or you want to deploy your code on a website or a server, these are probably good places to start.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/deploying-applications.html

https://docs.python.org/3.0/howto/webservers.html

EDIT: Added this as another useful link:
https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: It's a complex project (several modules and packages) but it was designed in a virtual environment.  How do I put everything together to run on my work machine (Which also has Python3)?

Comment: You can use pip to install any modules you need and also use it to set up a virtual environment on your machine: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/